# Process Diagram is not highlighting in formsflow.ai

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

I have been using the latest formsflow.ai. Submitted a form, the task is created and the application history was also generated but the process diagram is not highlighted. Process diagram page is shown like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you share any bpm camunda logs . Would help in debugging the issue.